# Polish letter while using sphinx math

Tags: python, html, css, python-sphinx

Is there a way to use polish letters (ę, ą) in mathbase (.. math::) sphinx?
In solution below the ę letter is smaller than the rest. Any ideas?

```
\text {napięcie}
```

Result:

[image: smaller ę than the rest of word]

**Its seems that sphinx is creating another span styles for my elements. Is there a way to change those elements in my .css to be 100% size?**

[image: Created span]

Comment: Please post your code directly to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - added those lines to my .css

> .MathJax span {   text-align: left !important;  }
>
> .test {   font-size: 100% !important; }
>
> .mtext span {     font-size: 100% !important; }